# How can I download Chromium for Windows Linux Subsystem?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to download Chromium normally with `snap install chromium` or `apt-get install chromium-browser` I end up getting the following.

`Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.`

Is there any workaround?